# odom → base_footprint

Tags: navigation, simulation, odometry, stage, base-footprint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Stage_ros publishes this, now I want to try simulating using STDR but it doesn't use the same nomenclature. How can I calculate this transform and what does it represent exactly in a real world scenario.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193372/odom-%E2%86%92-base_footprint/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-09-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been answered [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/12770/base_link-to-base_footprint-transform/)

---

Originally posted by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) with karma: 4518 on 2014-09-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-09-24**:
Here is the parent-child relationship when I run stage_ros
map -> odom -> base_footprint -> base_link -> rest of robot joints
so I don't see how your link is going to help me with the odom -> base_footprint part

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-09-24**:
It tells you what base_footprint represents, which you can use to recreate it in STDR. Since it's a 2D simulator I'm guessing you can just add an identity transform from base_link to base_footprint.

**Comment by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on 2014-09-24**:
I just want to know what odom -> base_footprint or generally speaking odom -> robot represents.

**Comment by [paulbovbel](https://answers.ros.org/users/3632/paulbovbel/) on 2014-09-24**:
Have a read [here](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/RobotSetup/Odom)